# CSS styling help for my form input

Tags: html, css

HTML FILE

```
<label for = "about"> About:</label>         
<textarea name="message" class="text" required></textarea>
```

CSS FILE

```
    label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    }
```

I need a CSS file to move the **ABOUT:** text to the bottom left of the text box

[image]

I need CSS to make it look this way

[image: How it should look after CSS]

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO is not a markup writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
label {
  /* display: inline-block;
  float: left; */
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for="about"> About:</label>
  <textarea name="message" class="text" required></textarea>
</div>
```

Try to use `display: flex;`

Comment: Are you using `inline-block` and `float` and `flex` at the same time so the browser can fall back on one if the other isn't supported?

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm sorry. I didn't see.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `float:left`, I used `vertical-align:bottom;` for placing the label at the bottom and added some margin to the element!

```css
label {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="about"> About:</label>
  <textarea name="message" class="text" required></textarea>
</div>
```

**References:**

1. [CSS vertical-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick it to the bottom of that section. I like to do that with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0;`. There is no need to add extra div as you can just do it with those two properties.

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute:
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 90px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9yf4wumd/